# UI Bootstrap not working in combination with $sce.trustAsHtml()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angularJs (v1.4.7) and ui.bootstrap in combination with html code that I am getting with REST API.
The problem is: if I get html with ui.bootstrap directives inside, it is not displayed properly (directives are not "translated" into html code like they should).
If I copy-paste that same html directly into my html, then it is ok. So I suppose that ui.bootstrap directive is executing before html code is inserted (or isn't executing at all).

Is there any workaround for this?

Simplified code snippets:

Ctrl:

```
FsDao.readDoc().then(
    function (d) {
        $scope.docHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(d.html);
    },
    function (error) {
        MainUtil.growl(Msg.DATA_ERROR, "danger");
    }
);
```

index.html:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="false">
    <div ng-bind-html="docHtml"></div>
</uib-accordion>
```

HTML (d.html)

```
<p style="text-align: right;">Some txt</p>
<uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="doc.open">
    <uib-accordion-heading>HEADING 1</uib-accordion-heading>
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
    </ul>
</uib-accordion-group>

<uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="doc.open">
    <uib-accordion-heading>HEADING 2</uib-accordion-heading>
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
    </ul>
</uib-accordion-group>
```

Comment: What happens if you put an `ng-if` in there? `<uib-accordion close-others="false" ng-if="docHtml"><div ng-bind-html="docHtml"></div></uib-accordion-group>`

Comment: @Kinglish I like your idea :) Unfortunatelly it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component like this:

```
app.directive('customComponent', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(elem, attrs) {
            return '<div></div>';
        },
        scope:false,
        link:function(scope, element, attr){
            if (typeof(attr.template) == "string") {
                var innerComponent = $compile(attr.template)(scope);
                element.append(innerComponent);
            }
        },
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Then use this component in your code:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="false">
    <custom-component template="{{docHtml}}"></custom-component>
</uib-accordion>
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/avgustin/qnj45v1a/

Comment: I get no output in this case. I included the directive in my index.html, tried with $scope.docHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(d.html); and with just $scope.docHtml = d.html; I get no error, but also no output.

Comment: @ljerka Check my fiddle example. Is working perfectly for me. I am using some code also in the app. In the example I am using 3 different way how to interpolate html. https://jsfiddle.net/avgustin/qnj45v1a/

Comment: Fiddle works for standard html, but so is my code. The problem is with uib directives.